# Powershell CSV grouping data by fields

Tags: powershell, csv, sccm

I have a big struggle here, I was asked to create a big script that will perform certain actions in SCCM Console, based on Variables taken from a CSV file. 
I have covered the SCCM scripting part as I thought it will be harder...but it appears that I have no idea how to read data from CSV...

Is it possible to get data from a file that looks like:

```
Hostname  Hours  Date
S1        14-15  05.05.2019
S2        14-15  05.05.2019
S3        9-13   06.05.2019
```

And use powershell to create variables that will contain all hostnames that share the same data from "Hours" and the same Date from Date column?

The reason I need this, is because I will be creating collections in SCCM with this logic:

- Create a collection that contains all hostnames from Hostname table, with a name that is a combination of time and date( "Myname 14-15 05.05.2019") and then
- editing properties of that collection to input data read from Hours column to set maintenance window(which basically means I will use a variable that contains Hours and Date input, and just put it into maintenance window with powershell cmdlet made for such purpose)

Is there any way to do that, and is it even possible to get the data to look like I need it?

Comment: `$Data=Import-Csv C:\Path\To\File.csv; $Data | Group Hours,Date` should do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a csv file `input.csv`

```
Import-Csv .\Input.csv | 
  Group-Object Hours,Date | 
    ForEach-Object {
      [pscustomobject]@{
        Name      = "Myname {0} {1}" -f ($_.Name -Split ', ')
        HostNames = $_.Group.HostName -Join '; '
      }
    }
```

yields:

```
Name                    HostNames
----                    ---------
Myname 14-15 05.05.2019 S1; S2
Myname 9-13 06.05.2019  S3
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this pushed me further in my code, I will base on it: )